# Analyse python project imports

Tags: python

In general I would like to understand what exactly code the code in my projects is actually using from a big framework.

First I want to know what are all the imports (possibly with static analysis), and then if possible which of these imports are actually used.

For the first problem I could use a regexp of course, but I would like to find a cleaner way.
but I don't see how with ast/inspect/parser.

And about the second problem I should be able to find out automatically if some of the imports are actually unused, but how can I do that?

EDIT:
about the second issue maybe the best way is a simple import hook, which just records everything it was imported and then call the default importing mechanisms.

So I tried something like:

```
class MyLoader(object):
"""
Loader object
"""

def __init__(self):
    self.loaded = set()

def find_module(self, module_name, package=None):
    print("requesting %s" % module_name)
    self.loaded.add(module_name)
    return self

def load_module(self, fullname):
    fp, pathname, stuff = imp.find_module(fullname)
    imp.load_module(fullname, fp, pathname, stuff)
```

But trying to import "random" I get
    from **future** import division
ImportError: No module named **future**

Which I think means I'm missing something..
I haven't found any simple example of using imp to do some import introspection, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with such an analysis would be the dynamic nature of python. In fact the set of modules that are used may be dependent on the runtime variable (i.e. some modules could be imported and used under certain runtime conditions only).

May be not the best way, but if you have pretty decent test coverage for your code, you can use coverage.py output to check what modules were loaded during the test execution.

Comment: Yes sure, to have a clear view of what really happens static analysis doesn't work very well. Pylint, however, does quite a good job, but I think it does an heavy parsing-job of the code..

See above for my attempt with the importer protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pleased to say that listing out the imports is actually quite simple.

I need a minimal implementation of the Importer protocol (defined by PEP 302), where if find_module returns None it will just fallback to the next one.

This simple script can actually show the imports done by the program passed in:

```
import sys

class ImportInspector(object):

    def find_module(self, module, path):
        print("importing module %s" % module)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    progname = sys.argv[0]
    # shift by one position
    sys.argv = sys.argv[1:]
    sys.meta_path.append(ImportInspector())

    code = compile(open(progname, 'rb').read(), progname, 'exec')
    exec(code)
```

Given this, any kind of trick can be implemented on top of it. 
For example we can keep track of the imports in a set and store them all when the program quits.

I think we might even get the hiearchy of the imports and produce a graph similar to what gprof2dot does, but only based on the analysis of the imports.